# U-SQL Ignore Empty Files

Tags: u-sql

I receive a daily dump of files from a data provider. On occasion we  receive empty files (20bytes). Is there any way to automatically avoid processing or skip these files?

I have tried:

```
USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows:1, silent:true);
```

But I seem to get a vertex failure related to what I believe is the empty files.

Comment: Can you please share the error details?

Comment: The solution below solved my problem, and am adding the error in case anyone else comes across this issue:

End of the first vertex stream segment is reached while trying to skip 1 rows from the input stream. Actual rows skipped: 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently added a FILE.LENGTH property as a computed virtual column that you can use to filter out files of a certain size.

For example the following should only operate on the files that are larger than 20 bytes:

```
@data = 
  EXTRACT 
          // ... columns to extract
        , file_sz = FILE.LENGTH()
  FROM "/mydata/{*}"
  USING Extractors.Csv();

@res =
  SELECT *
  FROM @data
  WHERE file_sz > 20;
```